# Segmentation fault: 11 when trying to perform char[] lookup in C

Tags: c

```
char getType()
{
    typedef struct typelookup { const char *opcodebits;  char instype; } typelookup;
    typelookup table[] = {
         {"000000",'r'},
         {"000010",'j'},
         {"000011",'j'},
         { NULL }
    };
    for (typelookup *t = table; t->opcodebits != NULL; ++t) {
        if (strcmp(t->opcodebits, opcode) == 0) {
             return t->instype;
        }
    }
    return 'i';
}
```

I need to be able to perform a lookup based on a string. The string is contained in a static array and if the string is in the lookup table, I want to be able to return a character which will define which type of MIPS instruction the binary refers to, hence the r, j and i as return values. This code compiles ok but when it comes to running the code I always get a "segmentation error: 11". Can anybody enlighten me as to what I'm doing wrong? Been trying to fix this error for longer than I care to admit.

Comment: Sentinel data is required for `t->opcodebits != NULL`. and `char * getType()` --> `char getType()`

Comment: what is opcode here...return type is not matching with the definition of getType....mainly, did you compile this code...

Comment: I've made changes to this based on your comments. To clarify, opcode is the name is of a static array that would contain "000000". I expect the function to return 'r' but instead it returns 'i'. Any idea why it is breezing past the entry in the table that corresponds to 'r'?

Comment: what does the debugger say & where does it go bang

Comment: Some coding advices: 1. Declare that `typedef` **outside** the function. 2. Use `for (int i=0; i<sizeof(table)/sizeof(*table); i++)` instead of looping until `NULL`. 3. Share with us what `opcode` is!!!

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, the problem has now been fixed. Opcode shall remain a mystery haha :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is `opcode`? Does the char array pointed to by `opcode` contain a terminating zero? If not, `strcmp` may keep comparing beyond the end of `t->opcodebits`, run out of bounds, and suddenly hit a non-readable virtual address.

I apologise for my answer sounding like a lot of additional questions. :-)

Comment: I did't have a null terminating character in the array. I've added it and it has fixed the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, but what are the bytes in it?

Comment: I've edited my first comment as I accidently added the comment when I wasn't finished. Thanks again :)

Comment: @user2998221 - SzG's answer fixed your "Segmentation fault". You should accept his answer to let other visitors with the same issue know that this solution fixed yours and may be the solution they need.